# Canonical Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup. Let $\pi\colon G \to  G/N$ denote the canonical homomorphism. Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\pi(H) = \pi(HN)$. Then prove that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then $\pi(H) = \pi(K)$ if and only if $HN = KN$.

I have been able to show that if $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ then $HN$ is also a subgroup. But I am not really sure where to go to from there.

Comment: Use the fact that $\pi(g) = N$ iff $g\in N$

Answer (score 2):

$H \subseteq HN$ implies that $\pi(H)\subseteq\pi(HN)$

Any element of $\pi(HN)$ looks like $(h.n).N$ for some $h\in H$ and $n\in N$. We have to find an element $h_1$ of H s.t $(h_1).N=(h.n)N$ i.e. $((h_1).(h.n)^{-1} )\in N$ i.e. $h_1.n^{-1}.h^{-1}\in N$

So, we can choose our $h_1=h$ because $h.n^{-1}.h^{-1} \in N$ as N is normal

For the second part, assume $\pi (H)=\pi (K)$

To prove, $\pi (HN)=\pi(KN)$ Take $h.n\in HN$ $\pi(h.n)=(h.n).N$

To show $\pi(h.n)=(h.n).N\in \pi(KN)$

i.e. $\exists k_1\in K$ and $n_1 \in N$s.t. $(h.n).N=(k_1.n_1).N$

i.e. $h.n.(k_1.n_1)^{-1} \in N$

then $\pi(h)=h.N\in \pi (H)=\pi (K)$ i.e. $\exists k_2\in K$ $(h).N=(k_2).(N)$ i.e. $(h).(k_2)^{-1}\in(N)$

Let us say $n_2=h.(k_2)^{-1}$ i.e. $h=n_2.k_2$ it follows  $h.n=n_2.k_2.n$

i.e.$h.n.(k_2.n)^{-1}=n_2 \in N$

So our $k_1=k_2$ and $n_1=n$

Therefore, $\pi(HN) \subseteq \pi(KN) $

The inverse inclusion can be shown similarly.

Now, if $HN=KN$ implies $\pi(H)=\pi(K)$ obvious

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: (1) As $H \subseteq HN$, $\pi(H) \subseteq \pi(HN)$, for the other inclusion let $h \in H$, $n \in N$. Can you find an element $h' \in H$ with $hnN = h'N$ (this will give you $\pi(HN) \subseteq \pi(H)$).

(2) If $HN = KN$ then (1) gives you $\pi(H) = \pi(K)$. For the other direction, try to identify the subgroup $\pi^{-1}\bigl(\pi(H)\bigr)$ as $HN$.

Comment: The map $G \rightarrow G/N $ is given by $g$ goes to $g.N$